# Could anyone help me how to stop recursion of future method by process builder

Tags: apex, process-builder, future

public class LeadConvertClass {

```
@future(Callout=true)
public static void futureCallout(List<String> ledIds){

    LeadStatus status= [Select Id, MasterLabel FROM LeadStatus WHERE IsConverted=true Limit 1];
    List<Database.LeadConvert> lstLeadConvert = new List<Database.LeadConvert>();

    for(Id currentlead: ledIds){
            Database.LeadConvert ledConvert= new Database.LeadConvert();
            ledConvert.setLeadId(currentlead);                
            ledConvert.setConvertedStatus(status.MasterLabel);
            ledConvert.setDoNotCreateOpportunity(TRUE); 
            lstLeadConvert.add(ledConvert);
    }
    if ( lstLeadConvert.size() > 0 ) {

        //FlagFutureClass.flag = true;
        List<Database.LeadConvertResult> converter = Database.convertLead(lstLeadConvert);
    }
}
@InvocableMethod(label='Customized Lead Convertion')
public static void invokeMethod(List<String> ledIds){

    //FlagFutureClass.flag = false; 
    futureCallout(ledIds);
}
```

}

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that by setting a static variable in the APEX class.

The value of static variable persists for whole transaction, thus no matter how many times your invocable method is called, the value of static variable will persists. You can use this mechanism to control recursion.

```
public class LeadConvertClass {
public static boolean isFutureCalled=false;//Boolean variable to control recursion. 
@future(Callout=true)
public static void futureCallout(List<String> ledIds){

    LeadStatus status= [Select Id, MasterLabel FROM LeadStatus WHERE IsConverted=true Limit 1];
    List<Database.LeadConvert> lstLeadConvert = new List<Database.LeadConvert>();

    for(Id currentlead: ledIds){
            Database.LeadConvert ledConvert= new Database.LeadConvert();
            ledConvert.setLeadId(currentlead);                
            ledConvert.setConvertedStatus(status.MasterLabel);
            ledConvert.setDoNotCreateOpportunity(TRUE); 
            lstLeadConvert.add(ledConvert);
    }
    if ( lstLeadConvert.size() > 0 ) {

        //FlagFutureClass.flag = true;
        List<Database.LeadConvertResult> converter = Database.convertLead(lstLeadConvert);
    }
}
@InvocableMethod(label='Customized Lead Convertion')
public static void invokeMethod(List<String> ledIds){

    if(isFutureCalled==false && !System.isFuture()){// Checking condition to avaoid recursion
       futureCallout(ledIds);
         isFutureCalled=true;
      }

}
}
```

You can read more here: https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000133752&language=en_US

Comment: The way you've written it, you'd set `isFutureCalled` to `true` after enqueuing the `futureCallout` method, but then the transaction would end. In a separate transaction, `futureCallout` would run, and if it triggers the Process Builder then `invokeMethod` would find `isFutureCalled==false`. Try moving the `isFutureCalled=true` inside the `futureCallout` method instead. That way if `invokeMethod` gets called in the same transaction it will abort the loop.

Comment: @CharlesT 

Thanks a lot it works perfectly....:)

Comment: @Pranay Jaiswal
Thanks Pranay
Your comment make sense to me but according to Charles T it works well.

Comment: if you have a transaction with > 200 recs, the static variable will prevent records 201+ from doing anything

Comment: @CharlesT each future call is a different transaction, If you move isFutureCalled=true inside the future Calls then multiple future calls can be triggered. Edited answer to avoid future call chaining by checking System.isFuture() before setting futureFlag.